# How Java code executes SQL query on database after making connection

Tags: java, sql

What happens when Java code executes SQL query on database, either using prepared statement or statement?

Comment: What exactly your looking for??

Comment: I am looking for technical insights of data retrieving procedure from Java Code

Comment: Have a look at the source code for the MySql JDBC driver [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j); you can't get a more technical insight than that :)

Answer (score -1):

The question is rather broad. If you are looking for something to start with, I would suggest you to start with some JDBC basics, e.g. this [JDBC official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). It explains how basic JDBC entities work and what's their role: how the connection is made, on which side queries are executed, what are different JDBC connection modes and so on.

After that, you should have a more specific set of questions: e.g. on how the database is structured or what are the differences between database types (relational vs. object). Since that, start looking for documentation on these databases.

Also check: [A brief explanation : how JDBC works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227181/a-brief-explanation-how-jdbc-works), where users answer on related basic questions about Java & DB interaction.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231), [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, I've elaborated my answer. Hope it now feels better

Comment: This is still not an answer, mostly because the question is not a question appropriate for SO.

Comment: I've already raised an appropriate flag and helped a user where to look for additional information. What's wrong with that @nicomp ?